# NoneType error converting OpenGl script from .py to .exe using cx_Freeze

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, cx-freeze

I have a few python scripts that I have been able to convert to .exe relatively easily with cx_Freeze but I have hit a bump with a rubixcube I am creating with opengl.

I have two scripts;

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
#go to dir in cmd, run python setup.py build or; setup.py build... will create a folder build with name.exe
setup(
    name = "Cube",
    version = "1.1",
    description = "Cube",
    executables = [Executable("OwnCube.py", base = "Console")])
```

OwnCube.py is simply;

```
import pygame

from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

It then saves a build folder under 'Cube' with a .exe file called 'OwnCube.exe' along with all the dll's and data files. Running OwnCube.exe in cmd gives a nonetype error.

```
G:\Programs\PersonalPrograms\PythonScripts\Cube\build\exe.win32-3.6>OwnCube.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 14, in run
    module.run()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "OwnCube.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\GL\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from OpenGL import error as _error
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\error.py", line 12, in <module>
    from OpenGL import platform, _configflags
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    _load()
  File "C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\__init__.py", line 29, in _load
    plugin = plugin_class()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have done this multiple times with other libraries but I can't seem to get this working with OpenGl, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i meet this problem too, and all i have done to solve this is add `OpenGL.platform.win32` in `includes` of setup.py. i use win10.
reason of this bug is :

```
def load( self ):
    """Attempt to load and return our entry point"""
    try:
        return **importByName**( self.import_path )
    except ImportError as err:
        return None
def importByName( fullName ):
    """Import a class by name"""
    name = fullName.split(".")
    moduleName = name[:-1]
    className = name[-1]
    module = __import__( ".".join(moduleName), {}, {}, moduleName)
    return getattr( module, className )`
```

cx_freeze can not catch `__import__` in your code, so we need to use import instead of `__import__`.

Answer (score 0):

After much hair pulling.

Turns out I needed to include an options line in setup to include the OpenGL Library. Then I had to either set the environment variable to the TCL_LIBRARY and TK_LIBRARY or manually. I did this in the script as follows:

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable



build_exe_options = {"includes": ["OpenGL"]}
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'G:\python path\tcl\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'G:\python path\tcl\tcl8.6'
#go to dir in cmd, run python setup.py build or; setup.py build... will create a folder build with name.exe
setup(
    name = "Cube",
    version = "1.1",
    description = "Cube",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages": ["OpenGL"]}},
    executables = [Executable("OwnCube.py", base = "Console")]
    )
```

I don't really understand why this happened, My guess would be that when compiling the OpenGL librarys to .dll or .so files it couldn't find the library tkinter or tcl that OpenGL was calling internally.

Hope this helps future searchers.